# Problema al enviar datos en un form con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

He realizado un form para el envío de reclamos, ya tengo la base de datos y estos son los archivos que tengo, y al ejecutar no me aparece ningun error en php pero tampoco envía nada a mi base de datos, dónde está el error?, por favor, ¡gracias!

index.html

```
<form action="reclamo.php" method="post" class="form-box">
                <h3 class="h4 text-black mb-4">1. IDENTIFICACIÓN DEL CONSUMIDOR RECLAMANTE</h3>
                <div class="form-group">                 
                        <input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" class="form-control" placeholder="Nro de Documento de Identidad" required>
                        <input type="text" id="nombres" name="nombres" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombres" required>
                        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
                        <input type="text" id="domicilio" name="domicilio" class="form-control" placeholder="Domicilio" required>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Nro Celular" required>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
                        <label><input type="checkbox" id="cbterminosservicio" name="cbterminosservicio" required><b> Acepto que el correo es un medio válido para la comunicación.</b></label>
                </div>
                <h3 class="h4 text-black mb-4">2. DETALLE DEL RECLAMO</h3>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select name="tiporeclamo" class="form-control">
                        <option value="Calidad del Servicio">Calidad del Servicio</option>
                        <option value="Actitud de Conductores">Actitud de Conductores</option>
                        <option value="Ruta no Cumplida">Ruta no Cumplida</option>
                        <option value="Mala Comunicación">Mala Comunicación</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Cuéntanos por favor, tu Reclamo/Queja:</p>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Textarea1" name="Textarea1" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group"> <br>
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-pill" value="Enviar Reclamo">

                </div>

                    </form>
```

reclamo.php

```php
<?php

include 'conection.php';

$codigo         = $_POST["codigo"];
$nombres        = $_POST["nombres"];
$apellidos      = $_POST["apellidos"];
$domicilio      = $_POST["domicilio"];
$phone          = $_POST["phone"];
$email          = $_POST["email"];
$cbcheckbox     = $_POST["cbcheckbox"];
$tiporeclamo    = $_POST["tiporeclamo"];
$Textarea1      = $_POST["Textarea1"];



$timezone="America/Lima";
$dt=new datetime("now",new datetimezone($timezone));;
$fechaActual = gmdate("d/m/Y H:i:s",(time()+$dt->getOffset()));

$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$insertar = "INSERT INTO bd_reclamos(CODIGO, NOMBRES, APELLIDOS, DOMICILIO, NRO CELULAR, CORREO, CHECKBOX, TIPO RECLAMO, TEXTO, FECHA_REGISTRO, USER_AGENT) VALUES ('$codigo', '$nombres', '$apellidos', '$domicilio', '$phone', '$email', '$cbcheckbox', '$tiporeclamo', '$Textarea1', '$fechaActual', '$user_agent')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $insertar);

mysqli_close($conn);

header('Location:confirm.html')
?>
```

conection.php

```php
<?php
$servername = "--------";
$username   = "--------";
$password   = "--------";
$database   = "--------";

// Create connection

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

?>
```

Tengo otro formulario, y si funciona correctamente, es en la misma base, en distinta tabla y los datos si llegan, y no se por qué con este form no ocurre lo mismo. Por favor, si pudieran ayudarme, se los agradecería mucho. ¡Graciaas!

Comment: pero el problema parece estar en que no has puesto ni siquiera los datos para conectarse a la base de datos. El problema parece estar en el archivo conection.php. Debes poner los datos de para conectarse a la base de datos como son el password y cosas parecidas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos errores de sintaxis

**corregido**

```html
<input type="text" id="phone"
```

en reclamo.php hacer referencia a **$_POST["cbcheckbox"]** cuando el **name** es **cbterminosservicio**

**corregido**

```php
$cbcheckbox = $_POST["cbterminosservicio"]
```

Comment: No tienes ningun control de errores para ver que sucede y que mensaje de error te está dando. Por ejemplo algo como: `if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($insertar)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));}`, esto iría luego de la línea del _"INSERT INTO bd_reclamos..."_

Answer (score 1):

tienes un doble ; al final de este código... $dt=new datetime("now",new datetimezone($timezone));;

No se ve si está seteado post  o if (isset ($_POST[" "]